# AngularCompilerPlugin not found

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

We're trying to build our Angular 6 application with AOT enabled. Unfortunately we always get the following error:

```
ERROR in Module build failed: Error: The AngularCompilerPlugin was not found. The @ngtools/webpack loader requires the plugin.
    at Object.ngcLoader (C:\frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:27:15)
```

Has someone seen this error before? I checked the *node_modules* folder, all files are there. This error does **NOT** occur if AOT is disabled.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm hitting the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but let me know if you found a solution. ;)

Comment: is there any solution on this ??

Comment: The error went away when I upgraded my dependencies to the latest Angular 7 version but I don't know what caused it unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Can you please post the complete, the most probably the error is due to you are trying  to compile non js resource and for which no suitable compiler is found.